# Visual Studio comments using images rather than text

Tags: c#, comments

I usually need to come back to old codes that I hardly remember after some weeks of work with other projects.

I try to write comments concisely, but still codes becomes messy.
Since I work mostly with computer geometry in Visual Studio C#, I was wondering if there is any "easy" way to add image comments rather than text?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often place such 'documentation' in a project subfolder...

Then use the local `FILE://` URI convention to link that image into my code comments or even XML markup (with the triple slash convention) which of course shows within intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

A comment can certainly *link* to an image (as a URL for example).  But no, you can't *embed* an image as a comment.  Code files are just text, not Word documents.

If the problem is that the code isn't clear and you're relying on comments to understand it, then the solution isn't to add more comments.  The solution is to write code more clearly.  Give variables semantically meaningful names, extract operations (every very small ones) into semantically meaningful methods.  The code itself should tell you exactly what it's doing.